# Jackson Deep Nested Objects

Tags: json, spring, rest, jackson

I have the following java JPA objects which are converted to json in my spring rest controller method, they are

```
class User{
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany
    private Portfolio portfolio;
    .....
}

class Portfolio {
     @JsonBackReference
     @ManyToOne
 private User user;

    @JsonManagedReference
     private List<Order> orders;
     .....
}

class Order {
     @JsonBackReference
 private Portfolio portfolio;

     private User user;
}
```

In my application I need 2 services:

> 1. Logon: 
>      returns the User object, with the Portfolio and List of Orders object, I don't need the Order.user object for this.
> 2. GetOrders: 
>      returns a List of Orders and I need the Order.user object with this.

Order.user is not the same as the parent User object.

My question is how to do I avoid an infinite recursion problem with the User object? Or is this just a bad design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` is that they handle a very specific kind of (direct) cyclic reference well, but are not designed to process anything outside of that narrow window (where a single parent object is directly related to one or more child objects). Unfortunately, your use case doesn't fall within that window.

So you have two options:

- Manual workaround - In your service class you would need to remove (make null) the `order.user` property, prior to serializing the top level `user` object. And conversely, you would need to remove (make null) the `user.portfolio.orders` property, prior to serializing the `orders`.
- Framework workaround - Upgrade to Jackson 2.0+ and use `@JsonIdentityInfo`. It can properly handle object references in graphs, many-to-many relationships, deep object trees, and more. [Some documentation and examples](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureObjectIdentity).

You *can* also get around the problem if you have control over the `ObjectMapper`. If you do then you simply need to specify a custom serializer to use depending on which of the objects you are returning, but since you are working within the Spring framework I do not believe you have direct control over the mapper.

My personal recommendation would be to upgrade your Jackson library and use `@JsonIdentityInfo`.

Comment: Good answer, seems like some learning to do with jackson, thanks